# Displaying an image in PHP using name stored in database

Tags: php, sql, image

I am trying to display an image that is in a folder "upload" by getting the image name from the database.

```
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  
  $pic =  $row['image']; 

  echo   $row['item'] ;
  echo  $row['location'];
  echo $row['description'];
  echo  $row['forum'];
  echo $row['datetime'];
  echo $row['username'];

 ?>


</br>


 <img src="upload/<?php echo  $pic ?>"/> 
 <?php echo  $row['image'];  } ?>
 "upload/<?php echo  $pic ?>"
 
 </body>
 </html>
```

[image]

As you can see it display everything except the img src.

[image]

This is my database (ignore BLOB that was a test). I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Might be a dumb question but your upload folder is in the same directory as your projectviewposted.php file?

Comment: view source (or use firebug) to see the image tag and see what is the src given there.

Comment: Sounds like a relative path problem.

Comment: What is happening when you try to open http://localhost/project/projectviewposted.php/upload/happyball (1).jpg ?

Comment: Upload folder is in the same folder as php file, when I go to the address you posted above, it displays same info

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to store the full relative path in the database like this:

```
uploads/folder/file.jpg
```

My preferred MySQL field type is 'varchar(255)' the your echo in te PHP code will look like:

```
echo '<img src="'. $row['image'].'" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print the image source outside the while-loop. The while-loop will only exit when `$row` is empty, so `$row['image']` is also empty.

Comment: If you look at the code closely the main img src is inside the loop, there is the closing } for the loop at the end.

Comment: Ok, I see it now. I think that says something about the readability of the code ;)

Answer (score 0):

1) view source (or use firebug) to see the image tag and see what is the src given there.

2) try the url: "http://{LOCAL}/projects/projectviewposted.php/upload/happyball(1).jpg" and see if you can open the image

Comment: It displays the same info when I try the full url

Comment: Definitely against using absolute URL path, it's the main reason for problems when we change domains an so on. From my personal experience I can suggest relative URL paths.

Comment: @h4cky: I only mentioned the full path so he could TEST if the image can open with full url !!!

Comment: I know, no offense. I just wanted to say that this is not good practice:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<img src="upload/<?php echo $pic; ?>"/> 
 <?php echo  $row['image'];  } ?>
 "upload/<?php echo  $pic ?>"
```

Else note down the link of the folder path. It might be that the folder path is not correct.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

      $pic =  $row['image']; 

      echo $row['item'] ;
      echo $row['location'];
      echo $row['description'];
      echo $row['forum'];
      echo $row['datetime'];
      echo $row['username'];

      echo '<br /> 
            <img src="upload/'.$pic.'"/> 
            '.$row['image'];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well after 3 days I figured it out... my header location was incorrect! 
../project/projectviewposted.php`/` A stupid extra slash at the end!!
Thanks for your help and suggestions!